# The garden where everything is possible

Tags: cipher

An old man spoke to me today.
He said: "A long time ago, I buried something very important. That was 20 years ago." After he said that, he gave me a note where it was written **"Hyih Jbimjbilom Ufogchcog"**.
To solve this, he said we need to travel back in time and we should ask Caesar. 
If you could solve it, go to the garden where everything is possible.

**Where is it buried?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It was buried in

> Nepal.

Hyih Jbimjbilom Ufogchcog

> Caesar cipher for "Neon Phosphorus Aluminium", or in short, Ne P Al.

The garden could be

> The Garden of Dreams in Kathmandu.

Comment: +1 You're good. I've some questions. Was this cipher so easy? And did you find out which garden it is? Edit: yes you're right with the garden!

Comment: @poisInANutshell Well it helps that there are online tools for the cipher in question ;)

Comment: and the key was to obvious am I right? I try to make it harder for the next time (i'm new and never did this before xD).